# Compose: LazyColumn recomposes all items on single item update

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

I am trying to show a list of Orders in a list using LazyColumn. Here is the code:

```
@Composable
private fun MyOrders(
    orders: List<Order>?,
    onClick: (String, OrderStatus) -> Unit
) {
    orders?.let {
        LazyColumn {
            items(
                items = it,
                key = { it.id }
            ) {
                OrderDetails(it, onClick)
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun OrderDetails(
    order: Order,
    onClick: (String, OrderStatus) -> Unit
) {
    println("Composing Order Item")
    // Item Code Here
}
```

Here is the way, I call the composable:

```
orderVm.fetchOrders()
val state by orderVm.state.collectAsState(OrderState.Empty)

if (state.orders.isNotEmpty()) {
    MyOrders(state.orders) {
        // Handle status change click listener
    }
}
```

I fetch all my orders and show in the LazyColumn. However, when a single order is updated, the entire LazyColumn gets rrecomposed. Here is my ViewModel looks like:

```
class OrderViewModel(
    fetchrderUseCase: FetechOrdersUseCase,
    updateStatusUseCase: UpdateorderUseCase
) {

    val state = MutableStateFlow(OrderState.Empty)

    fun fetchOrders() {
        fetchrderUseCase().collect {
            state.value = state.value.copy(orders = it.data)
        }
    }

    fun updateStatus(newStatus: OrderStatus) {
        updateStatusUseCase(newStatus).collect {
            val oldOrders = status.value.orders
            status.value = status.value.copy(orders = finalizeOrders(oldOrders))
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: The `finalizeOrders()` does some list manipulation based on orderId to update one order with the updated one.

This is how my state looks like:

```
data class OrderState(
    val orders: List<Order> = listOf(),
    val isLoading: Boolean = false,
    val error: String = ""
) {
    companion object {
        val Empty = FetchOrdersState()
    }
}
```

If I have 10 orders in my DB and I update one's status (let's say 5th item), then `OrderDetails` gets called for 20 times. Not sure why. Caan I optimize it to make sure only the 5th indexed item will be recomposed and the `OrderDetals` gets called only with the new order.

Comment: Did you find a way how to avoid all items recomposition in LazyColumn?

Answer (score 2):

Is the `Order`classs stable? If not it could be the reason why all the items get recomposed:

> Compose skips the recomposition of a composable if all the inputs are **stable and haven't changed**. The comparison uses the equals method

[This section](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lifecycle#skipping) in the compose's doc explains what are `stable` types and how to skip recomposition.

**Note**: If you scroll a lazy list, all invisible items will be destroyed. That means if you scroll back they will be recreated not recomposed (you can't skip recreation even if the input is `stable`).

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [Rebugger tool](https://github.com/theapache64/rebugger) to understand why your view was recomposed:

```kotlin
@Composable
private fun OrderDetails(
    order: Order,
    onClick: (String, OrderStatus) -> Unit
) {
    Rebugger(mapOf("order" to order, "onClick" to onClick))
    ...
}
```

The issue was in `onClick` in my case. Compose decided, that onClick is mutable, because it contains link to mutable object.

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote
> If I have 10 orders in my DB and I update one's status (let's say 5th item), then OrderDetails gets called for 20 times. Not sure why. Caan I optimize it to make sure only the 5th indexed item will be recomposed and the OrderDetals gets called only with the new order.

if you are calling `orderVm.fetchOrders()` in a composable, you are registering a flow collector at every recomposition, and, when they collect, they replace the state value and call another recomposition and so on.

Move the `orderVm.fetchOrders()` call to the ViewModel `init(){}` block, so, it will be registered only once.

If i am right, this is messing with the list...

```kotlin
orderVm.fetchOrders()
val state by orderVm.state.collectAsState(OrderState.Empty)

if (state.orders.isNotEmpty()) {
    MyOrders(state.orders) {
        // Handle status change click listener
    }
}
```

By the way, ideally, collect the flow inside a `viewModelScope`, so, it will be cancelled when the hosting viewmodel is cleared, avoiding memory leaks.

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

This can happen due to using a List instead of SnaphshotStateList, viewModel lambda not being stable or function itself not being stable.

For the ViewModel part you can instead of calling

viewModel.updateStatus or viewMode::updateStatus

you might need to call

```
val onClick = remember {
    { orderStatus: OrderStatus ->
        viewModel.updateOrderStatus(orderStatus)
    }
}
```

In this answer explained possible issues and how to solve them.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74700668/5457853